# Outlook Save MHT - Include BCC, Exclude Embedded Items, Display Addresses

Tags: com, outlook, outlook-2010, outlook-object-model, mhtml

I use C# and the Outlook 2010 object model to save Outlook emails to MHT format (MIME HTML). I have no problem saving an email as an MHT.

```
   //mi is a MailItem
   //Save As MHT
   mi.SaveAs(@"D:\test.mht", OlSaveAsType.olMHTML);
```

There are aspects of the resulting MHT that I would like to customize.

1. An Outlook-generated MHT file does not display the Bcc line of emails known to have Bcc recipients. These emails are taken from a sender's email store. Are there options to force the display of the Bcc line?
2. If the source email is a rich text formatted email and contains embedded files, Outlook stores the embedded files in the resulting MHT. Outlook does this well. However, I would like to purge the embedded files. Are there options to force Outlook not to write embedded files to the MHT? Saving as plain HTML is not an option because I want to retain in-line images.
3. An Outlook-generated MHT file shows the display name of each recipient. I would like for the MHT file to show the display name and the email address of each recipient. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do that, you would need to generate the MHT file yourself.